# Infer unbalanced mixture of beta distribution

Tags: machine-learning, inference, beta-distribution

Suppose data $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is a mix (union) of two groups $Y_1=\{y_1^{(1)},...,y_{n_1}^{(1)}\}$ and $Y_2=\{y_1^{(2)},...,y_{n_2}^{(2)}\}$, and $Y_1,Y_2$ are generated by two different beta distributions $\text{beta}_1(a_1,b_1)$ and $\text{beta}_2(a_2,b_2)$. The **task** is to infer which data entry belongs to which group, i.e. to get "labels" $l_i=1$ or $l_i=2$ for each $x_1,...,x_n$

> 1. Y_1 is much larger than $Y_2$, say $n_1=10n_2$
> 2. the mean of $\text{beta}_1$ is assumed to be smaller than $\text{beta}_2$, say $\frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1} =0.4,\frac{a_2}{a_2+b_2} =0.9$.

First, make an initial guess of $l_i$, e.g. $l_i$ = 2 if $x_i>0.6$, and otherwise $l_i=1$; so we have two "guessed" groups. The initial guess of $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2$ is by setting $b_1,b_2=1$ and $a_1,a_2$ such that $\frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1},\frac{a_2}{a_2+b_2}$ are the average of each "guessed" group. **Note the initial guessed group will be unbalanced as well**.

Then update formulas for the parameters are based on log-likelihood

> $\ln L=\sum\limits_{i = 1}^2 {(({a_i} - 1)\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{{n_i}} {\ln y_j^{(i)}}  + ({b_i} - 1)\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{{n_i}} {\ln (1 - y_j^{(i)})}  + {n_i}(\ln \Gamma ({a_i} + {b_i}) - \ln \Gamma ({a_i}) - \ln \Gamma ({b_i})))} $

The inference formulas are thus

> ${a_i} = {\psi ^{ - 1}}(\psi ({a_i} + {b_i}) + \frac{{\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{{n_i}} {\ln y_j^{(i)}} }}{{{n_i}}})$
>
> ${b_i} = {\psi ^{ - 1}}(\psi ({a_i} + {b_i}) + \frac{{\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{{n_i}} {\ln (1 - y_j^{(i)})} }}{{{n_i}}})$
>
> ${l_i} = \arg {\max _{{l_i} = 1,2}}\{ \ln L\} $

The **problem** is: the first iteration will already give high concentration $a_1+b_1$ to the larger group $Y_1$, because it contains much more data, so model seems to be "confident" in the mean of $Y_1$. The concentration $a_2+b_2$ for the smaller group will be like 3 to five times smaller.

> As a result, the iteration drives "marginal" data in the first group that is a bit far away from the mean to second group, and then becomes even more concentrated, and the second group becomes even less concentrated. ***It continues until the first group drives almost all its data to the second group***!

**Question**:

> What should I do in this situation? Is there any known technique for above problem, to infer group label for data from a mixture of beta distribution, preventing the high concentration of the larger group?

Comment: I didn't trt it, but my intuition tells me that adding a parameter for the probability to be in each group might help. Thus, the estimate for $ l_i $ will be weighted argmax instead of balanced argmax.

Comment: Why don't you use EM?